# Automatically remove referencing objects on deletion in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Let's suppose I have a schema like this:

```
var Person = new Schema({
    name: String
});

var Assignment = new Schema({
    name: String,
    person: ObjectID
});
```

If I delete a person, there can still be orphaned assignments left that reference a person that does not exist, which creates extraneous clutter in the database.

Is there a simple way to ensure that when a person is deleted, all corresponding references to that person will also be deleted?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can add your own `'remove'` Mongoose [middleware](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) on the `Person` schema to remove that person from all other documents that reference it.  In your middleware function, `this` is the `Person` document that's being removed.

```
Person.pre('remove', function(next) {
    // Remove all the assignment docs that reference the removed person.
    this.model('Assignment').remove({ person: this._id }, next);
});
```

Comment: what if it contains a deeper nested array of object ids? like `data:{persons:[{ObjectID}]}` ?

Comment: @vhflat Probably best to post a new question about that with all the specifics.

Comment: @JohnnyHK, but what about concurrency? What if an assignment is being created while the person is being deleted? I tried to resolve this issue in my answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/42521550 , but I feel there must be a better way! Can you please check it out?

Comment: @cute_ptr Right, you still have to make sure your app can handle the orphaned assignment case and then periodically remove orphaned objects to keep things tidy. This is what you take on with a non-relational database.

Comment: @JohnnyHK, What do you think about using `post remove hooks` instead of `pre remove hooks` to handle this (as suggested in my answer to that question) ?

Comment: Does this work on model-level calls? like model.findOneAndDelete(id)? The hook isn't firing for me.

Answer (score 18):

If by "simple" you mean "built-in", then no. MongoDB is not a relational database after all. You need to implement your own cleaning mechanism.

Answer (score 16):

#### The `remove()` method is deprecated.

So using 'remove' in your Mongoose middleware is probably not best practice anymore.

[Mongoose has created updates to provide hooks for `deleteMany()` and `deleteOne()`](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/7195).
You can those instead.

```
Person.pre('deleteMany', function(next) {
    var person = this;
    person.model('Assignment').deleteOne({ person: person._id }, next);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I had a couple questions: If `remove` is deprecated, why are you using it to remove the Assignments? Also, will the `deleteMany` hook be called if only one person is removed?

Comment: Haha, I'm using remove because I'm a lazy fool! :) Copy pasted Johnny's version and just tweaked the parts I changed in my own code. Thank you @PeterOlson for bringing this out! Given your experience you likely already know! I'll try to answer just to learn! Given the hooks seem to be tied to these functions, I'd deduce that `deleteMany` is always called when `deleteMany` is run yet not when a single person is removed through any other function such as `deleteOne`. Thanks for schooling me! :)

Comment: I tried looking through the source code to find out for sure but the code base is large so I wasn't able to chew through it. Either way, thank you, you inspired me to look in the source code. I'll see if I can test this out later as that will be another way to find out for sure.

Comment: To be honest I don't know the answer either (I haven't used Mongoose in a long while), I was just curious. Anyways +1 from me for keeping the information up-to-date!

Comment: @PeterOlson, I see! Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

You can leave the document as is, even when the referenced person document is deleted. Mongodb clears references which point to non-existing documents, this doesn't happen immediately after deleting the referenced document. Instead, when you perform action on the document, e.g., update. Moreover, even if you query the database before the references are cleared, the return is empty, instead of null value.

Second option is to use [$unset](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/) operator as shown below.

```
{ $unset: { person: "<person id>"} }
```

Note the use of person id to represent the value of the reference in the query.

Comment: in my opinion this is the answer, the referenced ObjectIds will still persist, howerver it does not matter, querying will not find them, neither they will throw an error. There is no reason to clean them im directly when the original document was deleted

Answer (score 6):

In case if anyone looking for the pre hook but for `deleteOne` and `deleteMany` functions this is a solution that works for me:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
... 

const PersonSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {type: String},
  assignments: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Assignment'}]
});

mongoose.model('Person', PersonSchema);

.... 

const AssignmentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {type: String},
  person: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Person'}
});

mongoose.model('Assignment', AssignmentSchema)
...

PersonSchema.pre('deleteOne', function (next) {
  const personId = this.getQuery()["_id"];
  mongoose.model("Assignment").deleteMany({'person': personId}, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(`[error] ${err}`);
      next(err);
    } else {
      console.log('success');
      next();
    }
  });
});
```

Invoking `deleteOne` function somewhere in service:

```
try {
  const deleted = await Person.deleteOne({_id: id});
} catch(e) {
  console.error(`[error] ${e}`);
  throw Error('Error occurred while deleting Person');
}
```

Comment: Can you explain, why one need to use `this.getQuery()["_id"]` instead of `this._id`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60018284/9399066 this also worked for me in case of delete (and is leaner)

Answer (score 2):

you can use soft delete. Do not delete person from Person Collection instead use isDelete boolean flag  to true.

Comment: This is a good practice, however it complexify a lot (particularly in this case) because in EVERY request you do you has to filter on `isDeleted` field

Comment: @538ROMEO you could use https://github.com/euqen/mongoose-paranoid-plugin

Answer (score 2):

Use `$pull`. Suppose you have a structure like this.

Stuff Collection:

```
_id: ObjectId('63dd23c633c17a718c4c5db7')
item: "Item 1"
user: ObjectID('63de669153bc12ecb9081b9e')
```

User collection:

```
_id: ObjectId('63de669153bc12ecb9081b9e')
stuff: array[ObjectId('63dd23c633c17a718c4c5db7'), ObjectId('63de3a69715ec134e161b0ea')]
```

Then after you remove the stuff:

```
const stuff = Stuff.findById(req.params.id)
const user = User.findById(req.params.id)

await stuff.remove()

// here you can use $pull to update
await user.updateOne({
   $pull: {
     stuff: stuff.id
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply call the model that needs to be deleted and delete that document like this:

PS: This answer is not specific to the question schema.

```
const Profiles = require('./profile');

userModal.pre('deleteOne', function (next) {
  const userId = this.getQuery()['_id'];
  try {
    Profiles.deleteOne({ user: userId }, next);
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
});
```

// in user delete route

```
exports.deleteParticularUser = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    await User.deleteOne({
      _id: req.params.id,
    });

    return res.status(200).json('user deleted');
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`error`, error);
    return next(error);
  }
};
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your answer might be more helpful to others if you explained how/why it works, and/or why this solution is better than the existing answers that have already been here for a while :)