# How to properly delete an orphaned reference in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

So, I am building a small blog-like project in Node, and I am running into an issue with orphaned database references.  I have two models in separate files that reference each other.

Here are my models:

```
// ./models/user   
Var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  posts: [{type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId, ref:'Post'}]
});

//  ./models/post
var PostSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  title:String,
  post_body: String,
  posted_by: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId
});
```

My question is when you delete say, a Post, how would you delete the reference in the User's post array?  My thinking was I could create a middleware to run before the delete route and delete the reference in the User's post array before I actually delete the post.  Would that be considered the best way to go about it?  I found a post on Stack that uses a 'pre' function in the schema like this:

```
 // ./models/post
 PostSchema.pre('remove', function(next){
    this.model('User').remove({posts: this._id}, next);
 });
```

Here is the actual stack post: [Automatically remove referencing objects on deletion in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11904159/automatically-remove-referencing-objects-on-deletion-in-mongodb) .  I could not get this work though.  I did ,however, implement a custom middleware to delete the references, but feel it might not be best practice.  Any tips/advice would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't want [`.remove()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.remove) here but you want [`.update()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update) with [`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) instead:

```
PostSchema.pre('update',function(next) {
    this.model('User').update(
        { },
        { "$pull": { "posts": this._id } },
        { "multi": true },
        next
    );
})
```

That's the correct operation to remove something from an array. The "multi" makes sure that the "post" would be removed for all `User` objects that reference it, thought it probably really is only one document anyway.

The `.remove()` method is for "removing" whole documents. The `.update()` method makes "changes" to documents.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of that.  Using update makes total sense here.  Appreciate that.  Now, I tried out the little snippet you posted, but the Object Id still remains inside the User's posts array.  In the pre function, I used both `PostSchema.pre('update' ...` and `PostSchema.pre('remove' ...`, but there is no removal of the reference.

Comment: I got it to work.  Apparently there is no query hook for 'remove'.  As stated in  the docs: 'If you set a 'remove' hook, it will be fired when you call myDoc.remove(), not when you call MyModel.remove()'.  I appreciate your help.  This is much cleaner/better than what I had going before.

Comment: I think using the middleware on ```update``` makes it delete the referenced data even when you are just updating the ```PostSchema```. doesn't it?

Comment: I tried to do a findOne + updateOne using mongoose but it does not always works. It fails to update the array at times without throwing an error when I am deleting items consecutively. Your suggestion of using an updateMany worked consistently but I do not know why.