# mongoose: middleware pre deleteOne options not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

documentation of mongoose says:

[Mongoose - Schema-pre](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema-pre<br/)

> Schema.prototype.pre():
>  Parameters:
>  The «String|RegExp» method
>   name or regular expression to match method name
>  [options]
>   «Object»
>   **[options.document] «Boolean» If name is a hook for both document and query middleware, set to true to run on document middleware.**
>   [options.query] «Boolean» If name is a hook for both document and
>   query middleware, set to true to run on query middleware.
>   
>  callback «Function»

And also about pre hook "deleteOne":
[Mongoose - middleware](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html)

> Document middleware is supported for the following document functions. In
>   document middleware functions, this refers to the document:
>   **...deleteOne**
>
> Query middleware is supported for the following Model and Query functions. In query middleware >functions, this refers to the query: 
>   **...deleteOne**

So, deleteOne is in Document and Query hook, now let's try to use this:

```js
mySchema.pre('deleteOne', { document: true }, function(next) {
  console.log(this)
  next()
})
```

Result: this refers to Query, not to Document. Why?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Oh, it is not clear from docs, that 'this' refers to document only in **document**#deleteOne.

So, the correct usage of 'deleteOne' hook is: 
In model:

```js
DocSchema.pre('deleteOne', { document: true }, function(next) {
  console.log(this)
  next()
})
```

later in code (in controller, etc):

```js
const doc = await DocModel.findOne({ name: 'myDoc' })
await doc.deleteOne()
```

Now 'this' refers to the document

Comment: Do you can we call this pre middleware on deleteMany call?
For example I have to remove all dependencies on 1 model. But removable element has another dependencies, so what should I call in second model?

Comment: I'm doing this, but it seems, it literally NEVER reaches document pre hook

Answer (score 4):

You need to add to the options: `{ query: false }`

If not the pre hook will run twice:

first for the document - the `this` will be the document

second for the query - the `this` will be the query

Write it like this:

```
DocSchema.pre('deleteOne', { document: true, query: false }, function (next) {
  console.log(this);
});
```

Comment: it is { document : true , query : false }

Answer (score 1):

Another way to get "this" run query inside hook

```
await ShopModel.deleteOne({ shop: shopDomain });

ShopSchema.pre("deleteOne", async function (next) {
  const shopDoc = await this.model.findOne(this.getQuery());
  await DiscountSettingsModel.findByIdAndRemove(shop.discountSettings);
  next();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to the [answer of Maxim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60018284/1839325), the definition of your pre middleware call has to be made before you compile the model (see [pre documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#pre)).

So you will have:

```
// Create schema
const DocSchema = new Schema(schemaFields)

// Attach middleware
DocSchema.pre('deleteOne', { document: true }, function(next) {
  console.log(this)
  next()
})

// Now create the model.
const DocModel = model('Doc', DocSchema)
```