# Reference array elements in same document of mongodb

Tags: mongodb, express

This is the mongo schema-

```
    {
        name: String
        description: String,
        array1: [{prop1: Number, prop2: String}],
        referencingArray: {prop1: String, prop2_array1ref: <array1 element ref>},
    }
```

Array elements of type object. One of the properties in `referencingArray` object need to refer to an element from `array1`. The UI will later use the referenced array element to annotate `referencingArray` info. The UI also needs to update `referencingArray` based on changes to `array1`. Currently `array1` objects do not have any uniquely identifying property.

One idea I have is to add a guid property to `array1` objects to uniquely identify them and make the `referencingArray` object's `prop2_array1ref` to use this guid. But that adds an extra property on the array1 objects.

Referring to `array1` objects via index will need to handle delete from array1. If `prop2_array1ref` is referring to index 0 element of `array1`, deleting the element at index 0 should put `referencingArray` in a bad state instead of silently referring to the new object at index 0.

Mongo assigns `_id` property to array objects. I thought of using the `_id` property of array objects in `prop2_array1ref` but I am not sure how to handle new entries when the array objects don't have an id yet.

Question:

What's the best way to refer `array1` elements from `referencingArray`?

Edit to add example:

```
    {
        name: 'John',
        description: 'Best guy',
        array1: [
          {prop1: 12, prop2: 'lorem'}, 
          {prop1: 55, prop2: 'ipsum'}
        ],
        referencingArray: {prop1: 'domur', prop2_array1ref: <array1 element 1 ref>},
        // User can change prop2_array1ref to point to different element of array1 in UI.
        // Question is what's a good value for prop2_array1ref?
        // Options are-
        //   1. Add guid to array1 elements and use that as value of prop2_array1ref. (e.g. 'fl3-42mnj-348hn-83ngns')
        //   2. index of array1 elements. (e.g. 1)
        //   3. mongo assigned _id of array1 elements. (e.g. 98702398420398)
    }
```

Comment: A small sample dataset ( just 2 docs) will help clarify the question.

Comment: @raga Added an example.

Answer (score 0):

A simple normalization will do the job:

**your main model**

```
{
    name: String
    description: String,
    array1: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Array1Model'}],
    referencingArray: {prop1: String, prop2_array1ref: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Array1Model'}},
}
```

**Array1Model**

```
{
    prop1: Number
    prop2: String
}
```

As you said yourself, mongo will implicitly add the primary key. Later on, if you want to render them nicely on the frontend, you do a simple "join"-like operation using `$lookup`. Here's an [example](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mongodb_join.asp).

Comment: This is a better variant of option 3 of using mongo provided id. I still need to handle adding new data.

Comment: Update:
Now I know what Enter key does in comments box and time limit on comment update.

Updating a object in the main document with a new element in array1 or update to an element will also be interesting to handle.

So far I have been doing simple validate and update. Guess I need to add logic during update.

Comment: As for an update and adding new elements to array1 - yeah, well, I believe it'd be same form, but your API endpoint would expect multiple objects within payload JSON. Then on server side you'd simply add corresponding records to Array1Model, store their generated IDs and update the main object's record. As for deletes from Array1Model and invalidating references in main object - I believe you could add your own middleware to handle that as in this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11904159/automatically-remove-referencing-objects-on-deletion-in-mongodb