# (MONGODB) How to remove referenced data when parent collection is deleted

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I have two schemas Folders and a model file as below.

FolderSchema

```
 const mongoose = require('mongoose')
 const {ObjectId} = mongoose.Schema

 const folderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title:{
      type: String,
    
     },

    belongsTo:{
     type:ObjectId,
     ref:"Project"
     }


 })

module.exports = mongoose.model("Folder",folderSchema)
```

modelFileSchema

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const {ObjectId} = mongoose.Schema


  const modelFileSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  createdAt: {
       type: Date,
       default: Date.now,
         },
  name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Uploaded file must have a name"],
        },
  image:{
         type:String
         },
   belongsTo:{
     type:ObjectId,
     ref:"Folder"
          }
         });


    const File = mongoose.model("ModelFile", modelFileSchema);


    module.exports = File;
```

The folder schema is the parent schema of the file. How can I delete the data from the file schema when I delete the folder. All the data in the file schema which belongs to the folder which is being deleted must be deleted as well. For example, I have a folder named A and Files 1,2,3 referencing folder A. When I delete folder A files 1,2,3 must be deleted as well.

Below is my delete folder code it's just to delete the folder. Files remain in the database.

Route.

```
 router.delete("/folder/delete/:folderId",deleteFolder);
```

Controller.

```
exports.deleteFolder = (req,res)=>{
let folderId= req.params.folderId
console.log(folderId);
Folder.findOne({_id:folderId}).then((resp)=>{
    console.log(resp._id)
    Folder.deleteOne({_id:folderId})
    .then(()=>{
        res.status(400).json( resp._id + " deleted")
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err.message)
    })
}).catch(()=>{
    res.send("Folder doesnot exist")
})
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use middleware for this.

```js
Folder.pre('deleteOne', function(next) {
    // Remove all the assignment docs that reference the removed person.
    this.model('ModelFile').remove({ _id: this._id }, next);
});
```

for more information refer to this post: [Automatically remove referencing objects on deletion in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11904159/automatically-remove-referencing-objects-on-deletion-in-mongodb)