# When the referenced object is deleted then how we can delete the objects that have references to it in fastapi and mongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, fastapi

I have a mongoDB document [A] containing a reference object id of another document [B].
Now when object [B] is deleted what is the best way to delete document [A] also b'coz it contains object id of document [B] which does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is at where place `object[B]` has been deleted, after that update `object[A]` or delete `object[A]` ,

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mongoose then you can write middleware to remove the referenced document. Reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11905116/1256333)