# Mongoose - reference array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I've referenced schema like this

```
var User = new Schema({
    following:[
            {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User'
        }
],
    followers:[
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User'
    }
]});
```

Think about A user follows B user. user A schema will be like this:

```
{
following[{User B}]
}
```

When i remove user B, User A still contains User B as a following user. How do i fix this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11904159/automatically-remove-referencing-objects-on-deletion-in-mongodb

Comment: Duplicate of [Automatically remove referencing objects on deletion in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11904159/automatically-remove-referencing-objects-on-deletion-in-mongodb)